# `gradle jar` doesn't seem to be adding dependencies to jar file

Tags: java, gradle, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-tasks-api

I'm wanting to make an executable file that will automatically create a Google Task list with associated tasks.

Right now, however, I'm trying to simply create an executable using the default code that Google provides [here](https://developers.google.com/tasks/quickstart/java). Once you add the `credentials.json` file (explained below) and enter `gradle run` (in the repo I've provided) in a terminal/cmd, it will work as expectedly.

However, if you run `gradle jar` to create a jar, you will get this error when you try to run the jar:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory

---

### How to reproduce

1. Clone [this repo](https://github.com/jp26jp/Google-Tasks-Error-Demo)
2. Download and replace the `credentials.json` file located in `./src/main/resources/` by clicking the "ENABLE THE GOOGLE TASKS API" on [this page](https://developers.google.com/tasks/quickstart/java).

   - If you want to confirm that the program works, set your terminal/cmd to the project's root and enter `gradle run`
3. Inside the project's root, enter `grade jar`. This will create a jar in the `./src/build/libs/` folder
4. Inside of the `./src/build/libs/` folder, run `java -jar demo-1.0.jar`

At this point, you will get the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want what's known as an "uber" jar (a jar that also contains its dependencies)

You can do this by

```
jar {
   from configurations.runtime.collect { zipTree(it) } 
}
```

Comment: Oh my god I love you with all of my heart. I've been going insane trying to figure that out.