# Gradle - cannot load a Java Class even when packed within the jar

Tags: java, gradle

My gradle build file is

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application
    id 'application'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
jar {
    from configurations.runtime
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Created-By':'Gmack',
            'Main-Class':'myapprunner.App',
            'Class-Path':'mydaos-1.0.jar'
        )

    }

}

allprojects{

  repositories {
      jcenter()
  }
}

subprojects {
   version = '1.0'
   apply plugin: 'java'
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.1-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Compile Project for dependency
    compile project(':mydaos')
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application
    mainClassName = 'myapprunner.App'
}
```

When I run the app using `java -jar myapprunner.jar`

I get a `ClassNotFoundException`

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mydaos.Library
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

I can confirm that the jar has been packed. Not sure why this is not picking things up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency classes (projects/external jars) aren't packed inside your jar by default.

You are using the application plugin which bundles your classes, your dependencies and an execution script in a zip so you should use that. The plugin also adds a "run" task to your project to run your main class via gradle for development purposes. See the [application plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) for more info

If you want to pack your dependencies inside your jar (known as an uber jar) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865762/gradle-jar-doesnt-seem-to-be-adding-dependencies-to-jar-file/56866203?noredirect=1#comment100281733_56866203). I suggest you stop using the application plugin if you do this

```
'Class-Path':'mydaos-1.0.jar'
```

This assumes that `mydaos-1.0.jar` is in the same folder you are running `java -jar ...` from which is likely not the case

Answer (score 1):

Plugin `java` is being applied twice and `com.mydaos.Library` is likely being pulled in from `compile project(':mydaos')` (or `'Class-Path':'mydaos-1.0.jar'`). Would assume the project does not build or the class path is wrong.